# yield has a rare behaviour

Tags: python, tuples, generator, yield

I am trying to write a generator and somethig is happening that I do not understand:

**PIECE OF MY CODE:**

```
def processTable(pathToTable, pages):

    #some code here to open PyTable, get node etc
    for i in pages:

        try:
            del aux10, aux11, aux20, aux21 
        except:
            pass


        aux10 = [row['value'] for row in tab.where('(done == 1) & (pageNr == i)')] 
        aux20 = [row['value'] for row in tab.where('(done == 2) & (pageNr == i)')] 
        aux11 = [row['value'] for row in tab.where('(done == 3) & (pageNr == i)')] 
        aux21 = [row['value'] for row in tab.where('(done == 4) & (pageNr == i)')]

        yield (i, np.array(aux10).mean(), np.array(aux10).std()), (i, np.array(aux11).mean(), np.array(aux11).std()), (i, np.array(aux20).mean(), np.array(aux20).std()), (i, np.array(aux21).mean(), np.array(aux21).std())
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

The expected output would be 4 values like:

```
a = ((element10_i, its_mean, its_std), (element_i+1, its_mean, its_std), ...)

b = ((element11_i, its_mean, its_std), (element_i+1, its_mean, its_std), ...)

c = ((element20_i, its_mean, its_std), (element_i+1, its_mean, its_std), ...)

d = ((element21_i, its_mean, its_std), (element_i+1, its_mean, its_std), ...)
```

So it works. I did like this:

```
>>import generatorTables as pro
>>from itertools import izip
>>testPages = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>gen = pro.processTable(pathToPyTable, testPages)
>>a,b,c,d = izip(*gen)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>a
((1, 9.034405600010885, 0.32797176526389787), (2, 9.0305521432119082, 0.33138509286206153), (3, 8.9994696778116783, 0.31336561331661922), (4, 9.0586203572673725, 0.31509917770176399), (5, 9.1253471514046396, 0.32446032765733307), (6, 8.9412112513166786, 0.31844521244534058), (7, 8.9666645705587129, 0.33561146807260173), (8, 8.797215574852185, 0.32094724030435973))
```

So, up to here everything is ok.
The problem is that, if for some reason I want to repeat the calculations, for example to measure time, I get this:

```
>>> del a,b,c,d
>>> a,b,c,d = izip(*gen)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

So I do not understad:

1. Why it worked before and not now
2. Why it sais "need more than 0 values to unpack"?? I thought I was doing good.

**NOTE:**

if anybody want to suggest any other way to yield these 4 values, it would be more than welcome.

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Generators generate values once.

Comment: Thanks, yes some other guy answered the same. It was my mistake since I thought that the generator object would be always available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a generator is that it only generates the values **once** and does not hold the values in memory.

If you want to reuse the values, you will have to create a new generator by calling the original function again, or use a `list` instead of a generator.

To create a new generator, just repeat the two statements:

```
>>gen = pro.processTable(pathToPyTable, testPages)
>>a,b,c,d = izip(*gen)
```

If you want a list instead without modifying the generator code, you can capture the output of the generator with a list comprehension.

```
gen = [x for x in pro.processTable(pathToPyTable, testPages)]
```

Comment: In other words, you need to rerun `gen = pro.processTable(pathToPyTable, testPages)` every time you want to iterate over `gen`.

Comment: Ok I knew that it holds the values in memory but, I didint know that you must create a new generator each time. I thought that, since generator is an object, you create it: `gen = pro.processTable(pathToPyTable, testPages)` and then you would have it available any time you want

Comment: @user2919052, Nope, it gets consumed.

Comment: yes It does not let me accept before 5 mins, but dont worry I will!!